# Armor sphere upgrade list

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

My current set in MH4U now is Rath Soul Armor (Azure Rathalos armor high rank). Now I want to get the maximum defense of this armor, so I decided to farm armor sphere. I look everywhere (wiki, kiranico, reddit, and some youtuber website), but I can't find what and how many armor sphere needed for maximum defence. The list in the wiki I found is not completed yet.

But if I look in that incomplete list, I guess armor in the same class (Low rank/High Rank/G Rank) have the same amount armor sphere needed to maximize the defence. Is there any complete list for armor sphere needed to upgrade into maximum defence per class (Low rank/High Rank/G Rank)?

Comment: Since you can upgrade low rank armor all the way to use g rank spheres, getting this info is a huge PITA.  However, upgrading a lower rank armor up to the next level is ALWAYS worse defense than building the next rank's armor.  You only do this if the skill and slot combination cannot be replicated.

Comment: Upgrade your set as much as you can, but get ready to make Rath Z to replace it.

Comment: Note that an Armor Sphere list is a very finite number of items.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it takes 1 or 2 of each armour sphere in upgrading armor. However, with a recent set of armor (Arc S) I upgraded the Chestplate with a HARD armorsphere and it then required a HEAVY armoursphere. Incase you were wondering what armorspheres there are;

Armor Sphere, Armorsphere+, **Advanced** Armor Sphere, **Hard** Armour sphere, **Heavy** Armoursphere, **Strong** armour sphere and then there is atleast one more afterwards.

Hope this helps.

(EDIT) The amount of Armor Spheres can differ, like my example above. With your Rath Soul (S I would think) armor, you would probably start around Advanced to hard armor spheres.  At the start of your upgrading, ONE of a certain armor sphere should be used before it uses a similar pattern as following:

> 1x ? Armorsphere > 2x/3x ? Armorsphere > 2x/3x ? Armorsphere

And So on, until you reach the last Armor Sphere. Then im not sure, as I've only ever made it to Tru (In 3U) and strong in 4U.

Comment: can you include the amount needed?

Comment: (Another Edit) If your armor is low rank, it should start with 2x/3x Armorsphere.

Comment: Note that not all class use True armor sphere after Hard armor Sphere, G Rank armor not use True Armor Sphere, Hard > Strong > Divine , so the list is not in the same type armor sphere.